# Loading Icons from a given path to display in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I have a tree that displays the directory and another panel that displays the files.  Right now the files displayed have no icons.  All i know is the path to the file.  What i woudl like to do is get that files icon to display in that panel.  I need the output to be and Image.source.  Currently this is what i have

```
    private ImageSource GetIcon(string filename)
    {
        System.Drawing.Icon extractedIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
        ImageSource imgs;

        using (System.Drawing.Icon i = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(extractedIcon.ToBitmap().GetHicon()))
            {
                imgs = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                        i.Handle,
                                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, 16, 16),
                                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }

        return imgs;
```

From there i call my itme and try to change its default icon with:

```
ImageSource i = GetIcon(f.fullname)
ic.image = i
```

`ic` is the given item to the list, f.fullname contains the path
here is the get and set of image

```
        public BitmapImage Image
        {
            get { return (BitmapImage)img.Source; }
            set { img.Source = value; }
        }
```

It doesn't work and this is one of many ways I've tried it says it cant cast the different types.  Does anyone have a way to do this?
I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that `img` is a standard `Image` control.

Your `Image` property is of type `BitmapImage`, which is a specific kind of `ImageSource`.  `CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` returns an instance of an internal class called `InteropBitmap`, which cannot be converted to `BitmapImage`, resulting in an error.

You need to change you property to `ImageSource` (or `BitmapSource`, which `CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` returns, and inherits `ImageSource`), like this:

```
public ImageSource Image
{
    get { return img.Source; }
    set { img.Source = value; }
}
```